# Standalone class clips text edges

Tags: standalone

I need to turn a list of about 300 names into images which are exactly the size of the text. My first thought was to use `standalone`, but that cuts off the edges of some letters (J, u, etc) So I tried adding an arbitrarily small border to it (`\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}`), which prevented the clipping, but unfortunately means that I can't use the images (I really need the resulting pdf edges to line up exactly with the visual edges of the text) Is there any way to achieve the desired effect?

My current code:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=1pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
Jane Doe
\end{document}
```

I am away from a computer right now, but if necessary I can upload an image of the clipping I'm seeing without adding the margin.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! That's because TeX can't "see" the glyph, it only knows about its bounding box, which not necessarily (actually rarely) match. You can check that by doing `\fboxsep0pt
\fboxrule1sp \fbox{J}`. You'll see that the J protrudes a little below the bounding box.

Comment: You can add a smaller margin, for example 0.1pt. You may also try another font, if that is an option.

Comment: @phelypeoleinik I figured that the problem was something to that effect. Does that mean there's no way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a vertical phantom letter on the baseline (which takes vertical space but no horizontal space) and then raise the actual text a little bit:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
\vphantom{X}\raisebox{0.3pt}{Jane Doe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or raise individual letters (and optionally adjust the kerning left and/or right of the letter):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
\kern-0.035em\raisebox{0.3pt}{J\kern-0.1em}\raisebox{0.1pt}{a}ne Doe
\end{document}
```

[image]